# jQuery function on blur stops working after jQuery datatables pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, pagination, datatables

I have a simple function which updates the database which works perfectly fine until you go past page 1 of the jquery datatable.  The pagination itself doesn't "break" it as you can go back and forth and it will only work on page 1.  As a quick example I can use it on page 1 (it works), I click to page 2 (it doesnt work on any rows) I click back to page 1 (it works again) all without refreshing the page ever.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    //acknowledgement message
    var message_status = $("#status");

    $("span[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
    var field_userid = $(this).attr("id") ;
    var value = $(this).text() ;
    $.post('processing/inline-edit' , field_userid + "=" + value, function(data){
        if(data != '')
        {
            message_status.show();
            message_status.text(data);
            //hide the message
            setTimeout(function(){message_status.hide()},6000);
        }
    });
});

});

</script>
```

This is basically how the table looks:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display table table-bordered table-striped" id="dynamic-table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Element</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

//php while loop here
<tr>
  <td><span id="element:'.$row['id'].'" contenteditable="true">....</span></td>
</tr>

.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) so that all matching elements loaded via ajax will be bound to the event.

```
$("body").on("blur", "span[contenteditable=true]", function() {
```

Comment: Wow! that was fast, it works perfectly!  I will accept the answer, however, I guess there is a time limit (you was too fast haha).  Will mark it later.  Thanks again